# Can terms of fibonacci series be negative?

Tags: c, fibonacci

I am trying to print the first 80 terms of fibonacci series but after certain range numbers appears to be negative.So, is this correct?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
        int i,first_term=0, second_term=1, next_term;
        for(i=0; i<80; i++)
        {
            printf("%d, ",first_term);
            next_term= first_term + second_term;
            first_term=second_term;
            second_term = next_term;

        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It is due to integer overflow. Kindly search on this topic [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) is one of the reference.

Comment: @Roberto A signed 32-bit `int` overflows on the 48th term.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I realized it soon after posting. You spotted me. :)

Comment: @BinduKhadka retry defining `long first_term=0, second_term=1, next_term;`

Comment: An unsigned 64-bit type will work up to 94 terms.  Signed up to 93.

Comment: Read about [bignums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) and consider using [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: Or use Python, which doesn't have integer limits :^)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your formula is correct. However, numbers in the Fibonacci sequence grow quickly, so your ints are overflowing. You can get more correct numbers if you use `long` instead of `int`, for example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned long long first_term=0, second_term=1, next_term;

    for(i=0; i<80; i++)
    {
        printf("%llu, ",first_term);
        next_term= first_term + second_term;
        first_term=second_term;
        second_term = next_term;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `long` assumes that that it's a 64 bit machine. Probably reasonable these days, but `long` on a 32 bit machine is 32 bits. `long long` [and `%lld`] are the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will update my answer. Don't you think using `unsigned long long` is better?

Comment: Yes. I assumed you'd catch that, as Mark's comment at the top mentions it (i.e.) you get one extra bit of precision and can't go negative--overflow would be noticing that term N+1 becomes less than term N

Answer (score 2):

This is due to integer overflow.

Fibonacci numbers can't be negative.

I would suggest you to use `long long int` or `unsigned long long int` as follows:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {

    int i;

    uint64_t first_term=0, second_term=1, next_term;

    for(i=0; i<80; i++)
    {
        printf("%llu, ",first_term);
        next_term= first_term + second_term;
        first_term=second_term;
        second_term = next_term;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**PS:** The fibonacci series grows very quickly. There can be overflow again with `long long int` and even `unsigned long long int` when numbers cross `18,446,744,073,709,551,615` which is the upper limit of unsigned long long int. Therefore, **BigInt for C++** will be beneficial.

Comment: It would be even better if you used `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` instead, because you get that extra bit and also fibonacci terms are always non-negative.

Comment: I suggest you use `#include <stdint.h>` and `uint64_t` as the type so you know what the bit-size is.

Comment: Thanks @MarkTolonen, updated the answer